# Netbeans Intellisense PHP Iterator Interface

Tags: php, intellisense, netbeans-6.9, type-hinting

I'm using Netbeans 6.9 and writing a PHP class that implements the Iterator interface.  I would like to have the IDE offer Intellisense as I iterate over the items in my object.  It seems to work for the Zend Framework as I've noticed that when iterating over a Zend_Db_Rowset I get intellisense for a Zend_DB_Row.  For example, when I write:

```
foreach($rowset as $row) {
  $row->delete();
}
```

When I type "$row->" Netbeans pops up its code hints for the member functions of Zend_Db_Row_Abstract.  Unfortunately, I can't get this to work for my own code.  Below is a sample I tried to get to work:

```
class Foo {

    private $value;

    /**
     *
     * @param string $value
     */
    public function setValue($value) {
        $this->value = $value;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getValue() {
        return $this->value;
    }

}

class It implements Iterator {

    private $data;

    public function __construct($data) {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Foo
     */
    public function current() {
        return current($this->data);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Foo
     */
    public function key() {
        return key($this->data);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Foo
     */
    public function next() {
        return next($this->data);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return Foo
     */
    public function rewind() {
        return reset($this->data);
    }

    /**
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function valid() {
        return key($this->data) !== null;
    }

}

$a = new Foo();
$b = new Foo();
$a->setValue('Hello');
$b->setValue('Bye');
$testData = array($a, $b);
$myIt = new It($testData);
foreach ($myIt as $obj) {
    echo $obj->getValue();
}
```

Strangely the intellisense seems to think $obj is an object of type It when I want it to think (and it actually is) an object of type Foo.

Comment: I just tried it, and what's curious is that my usual solution of `/** @var $obj Foo */` inside the `foreach` loop doesn't seem to work either. Netbeans (6.9.1) is very set in its notion that $obj is an `It`. Strange.

Comment: Try removing the second * in the /**.

Comment: +1 I still consider this to be a bug in Netbeans. It should not be that hard to extract the type from the current method. Apparently Netbeans thinks us PHP coders only iterate over arrays

Answer (score 2):

Within the body of the loop you can provide the type hint in a comment.

```
/* @var $obj Foo */
```

+1 for Brian Fisher's suggestion.